# C - copy buffer to string - is it even possible?

Tags: c, string, buffer

is it possible to copy buffer to a string? strncpy can copy string into an allocated string array, i'm wondering if this is possible to do the opposite

```
char *buffer[50];
fgets(buffer, 50, stdin);
//how can i assign string in buffer to a single string (char)?
```

Comment: your `buffer` is an array of pointers, not a character array.

Comment: `char` is a type for a single character, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

First, a C string is not just a `char`, but an array of `char` with the last element (or at least the last one that's counted as part of the string) set to the null character (numerically `0`, also '\0' as a character constant).

Next, in the code you posted you probably meant `char buffer[50]` rather than `char *buffer[50]`... the version you have is an array of 50 `char *`s, but you need an array of 50 `char`s.  After that's corrected, then...

Since `fgets()` always fills in a null char at the end of the string it read, `buffer` would already be a valid C string after you call `fgets()`.  If you'd like to copy it to another string so you can reuse the buffer to read more input, you can use the usual string handling functions from `<string.h>`, such as `strcpy()`.  Just make sure the string you copy it into is large enough to hold all the used characters plus a terminating null character.

This code copies the string into a newly `malloc()`ed string (error checking omitted):

```
char buffer[50];
char *str;
fgets(buffer,50,stdin);
str = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
strcpy(str,buffer);
```

This code does the same, but copies to a `char` array on the stack (not `malloc()`ed):

```
char buffer[50];
char str[50];
fgets(buffer,50,stdin);
strcpy(str,buffer);
```

`strlen()` will tell you how many characters are used in the string, but doesn't count the terminating null (so you need to have one more character allocated than what `strlen()` returns).  `strcpy()` will copy the characters and the null at the end from one string/buffer to another.  It stops after the null, and doesn't know how much space you've allocated -- so you need to make sure it will find a null character before running out of space in the destination, or reaching the end of the source buffer.  If in doubt, place a null at the end of the buffer yourself to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `char buffer[50];` and yes, you can then use `strncpy` (which does not care if it got a static or a heap allocated zone).

But I would recommend using [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) in your case.

Comment: input is just a single line made of a few words. I tried: char buffer[50];
char b;
strncpy(b,buffer,50); somehow it doesn't work. not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must have:

```
char buffer[50];
```

because otherwise you have an array of 50 `char *`s which is not what you want. That is, you read 50 chars from input and create addresses from them (which means "boom"!)

Second, yes, you can use `strncpy` to copy. Note that a string is basically an array of chars, terminated by `'\0'` (NUL). So in this case, `buffer` is indeed a string. You would want to copy the string only if you want to keep the original and modify the second (or keep a copy of original and then modify buffer). Otherwise, you can safely use the same buffer as the desired string.

Third, I don't know how exactly your input looks like, but what you want to do, you can most likely do it better with `*scanf` functions.